# Insert database multi-part/form-data not working (data not stored)

Tags: php, post, mysqli, insert, multipartform-data

I'm a newbie on php. I try this form but, it won't store data from input to database. Page reloaded but insert data still not work.
here's the connection

```
<?php $connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","geminpo"); ?>
```

here's the form

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="judul">
    <button name="save">simpan</button>
</form>
```

here's the php

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $connection->query("INSERT INTO artikel(judul)VALUES('$_POST[judul]')");
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you were missing the `'` when accessing the post array value:

```
 <?php 
    if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
        $connection->query("INSERT INTO artikel (judul) VALUES ('" . $_POST['judul'] . "')");
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, data still not stored yet.

Comment: @Arrizal how many columns that table (artikel) has? Can you post the table code? It might have other columns that can't be empty

Answer (score 0):

Button name is not submitted with the form then `$_POST['save']` is not set.
I suggest to use a hidden input :

```
<input type="hidden" name="save" />
```

Comment: Did you mean to add `<input type="hidden" name="save" />` below the button?  Or delete the button?

Comment: add the input anywhere inside the form, and keep the button with a different name